# Behavior of biggest prime divisor of $n$ as $n$ grows large

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, divisors-multiples

Let $P\subseteq \mathbb{N}$ be the set of primes, and for any integer $n>1$ let $L(n) = \max\{p \in P: p \mid n\}$ be the largest prime divisor of $n$. Moreover, for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ with $n>1$ we let $M(n)$ to be the **median** of the set $$\{L(m)/m : m\in \mathbb{N} \land 1 < m \leq n\}.$$

Does $\lim_{n\to\infty}M(n)$ exist? If yes, is its value known?

Comment: The number of distinct prime divisors of $n$ grows on average as $\log \log n$. This should give you that $\lim_{n \to \infty} M(n) = 0$.

Comment: What is the context for asking this question? It seems like a very random function.

Comment: suffices to show average is $0$. Can upper bound average by $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{2 \le m \le n} \frac{1}{m}\sum_{p \mid m} p = \frac{1}{n} \sum_p p \sum_{2 \le m \le n \\ p \mid m} \frac{1}{m} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_p p\sum_{1 \le k \le n/p} \frac{1}{pk} \le \frac{1}{n} \sum_{1 \le k \le n} \frac{1}{k} C\frac{n}{\log(n/k)} \le 2C/\log n$. So all we needed really was that primes have $0$ density (which is also necessary for the median/mean to be $0$).

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Please post one as an answer so we can close this thread. @Carl-FredrikNybergBrodda - the context was a silly one: I saw a car with a license plate "AB 639" and noticed that $639 = 3 \cdot 3 \cdot 71$ where 71 is much higher than the square root of 639. So I was wondering how "common" this phenomenon was and tried to put this hand-wavy question into some solid-ish mathematics.

Comment: @DominicvanderZypen You might be interested in the following result. Writing $L(n) = n^{\alpha(n)}$, the random variable $\alpha \in [0,1]$ has a continuous limiting distribution if $n$ is randomly sampled from $[1,x]\cap \mathbb{Z}$ and $x \to \infty$.

Comment: That's an interesing angle - thanks @OfirGorodetsky! Do you have a reference on this?

Comment: @DominicvanderZypen This result dates back to Karl Dickman's 1930 paper (in fact, the history is more complicated, and Pieter Moree wrote a great survey on it titled "Integers without large prime factors: from Ramanujan to de Bruijn"). A modern treatment can be found in Tenenbaum's book "Introduction to Analytic and Probabilistic Number Theory" (in the 1st edition this is in Chapter III.5, p. 367, Theorem 6). However, results such as "the probability that $\alpha<c$ tends to 0 as $c \to 0$" are much easier, see e.g. p. 359, Theorem 1 in the same book. (continued in next comment)

Comment: (cont.) Just to give an alternative source with a slightly different argument: Koukoulopoulos' "The Distribution of Prime Numbers", Theorem 14.5. For the weaker result we can argue as follows: We start with an elementary identity of Hildebrand, $\Psi(x,y) \log x = \int_{1}^{x} \Psi(t,y) \frac{dt}{t} + \sum_{p^m \le x, \, p \le y} \Psi(x/p^m, y) \log p$ where $\Psi(x,y)$ counts integers up to $x$ whose prime factors are $\le y$. The trivial bound $\Psi(t,y) \le t $ applied to the RHS leads to (continued in next comment)

Comment: (cont.) $\Psi(x,y) \ll (x/\log x) (1 + \sum_{p \le y} \log p /p) \ll x (\log y / \log x)$ (where the estimate $\sum_{p \le y} \log p/ p \ll \log y$ is due to Mertens). Throughout $p$ is a prime. This implies that the probability that $\alpha \le c$ decays like $O(c)$. The truth is closer to $(1/c)^{-1/c}$.

Comment: Thanks Ofir for taking the time to write this up! (It would have deserved an additional answer.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of prime divisors of $n$ grows typically as $\log \log n$. Suppose $n$ has $k$ prime factors. Now $n/L(n)$ has only $k-1$ prime factors, so
$$
k-1 \approx \log \log \frac{n}{L(n)} = \log \log n + \log\left( 1-\frac{\log L(n)}{\log n}\right) = k + \log\left( 1-\frac{\log L(n)}{\log n}\right)
$$
and hence
$$
\log\left( 1-\frac{\log L(n)}{\log n}\right) \approx -1
$$
i.e., typically we will have
$$
\log L(n) \approx \left( 1-\frac{1}{e}\right)\log n
$$
or indeed
$$
L(n) \approx n^{1-\frac{1}{e}} = n^{0.632...}.
$$
Note that this means that typically the largest prime divisor of $n$ will be bigger than $\sqrt{n}$, which is a nice isolated statement as well.

As mathworker21 noted, it suffices to show that the average of $L(m)$ for $1 < m \leq n$ tends to $0$ as $n \to \infty$. Let $A(n)$ be this average. Thus in the typical case
$$
A(n) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{m=1}^n \frac{L(m)}{m} \approx \frac{1}{n} \sum_{m=1}^n \frac{1}{m^{\frac{1}{e}}} = \frac{1}{n} H_{n,\frac{1}{e}}
$$
where $H_{n,\frac{1}{e}}$ is the $n$th generalized harmonic number of order $\frac{1}{e}$. As $n\to \infty$, an asymptotic expansion of this right-hand side yields
$$
A(n) \approx \frac{1}{n} H_{n,\frac{1}{e}} = \frac{e}{n^{1/e}(e-1)} + \frac{\zeta(\frac{1}{e})}{n} + O\left( \frac{1}{n^2}\right) \to 0
$$
as $n \to \infty$. Hence also $\lim_{n \to \infty} M(n) = 0$.

Comment: In the first line, how are you getting that $k-1$ is about $\log \log \frac{n}{L(n)}$? That would be true if numbers of the form $\frac{n}{L(n)}$  look typical, but that isn't obvious.